# How am I able to write Bangla without using UTF-8?

Tags: html, utf-8, bangla-font, bengali

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--<meta charset="UTF-8">--> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>আমার নাম ফারহান</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNOOb.png)

Even though I commented out `<meta charset="UTF-8">` I can still write in Bangla. How is this possible?

Comment: The content of a text file has no influence on the charset/encoding used to write it to disk. You can write "This is UTF-8 encoded" to a file even if it is not UTF-8. Most text editors or IDEs allow you to change the encoding used to write a file.

Comment: @lupz Why do we even bother writing `<meta charset="UTF-8">` then? What purpose does it serve if we can use any character we want without utf-8?

Comment: I struggle to find a definitive reference for this, but I think UTF-8 is the one and only valid encoding for HTML5 documents (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset). Still, this is a question of how this is handled by the browsers but I think this meta tag is an interpretation hint for older browsers. I suggest to use UTF-8 anywhere (unless there are valid reasons for using another encoding) and keep that line in your HTML documents. I like this article on encodings: https://kunststube.net/encoding/